# ChatMessageHistory into a Runnable langchain

Tags: langchain

So I have this

```
# Initialize ChatMessageHistory object
history = ChatMessageHistory()

# Loop through each message in the list
for message in messages:
    if message['is_from'] == 'human':
        history.add_user_message(message['message'])
    else:
        history.add_ai_message(message['message'])
```

I have this template

```
math_template = """You are a very good mathematician. You are great at answering math questions. \
You are so good because you are able to break down hard problems into their component parts, \
answer the component parts, and then put them together to answer the broader question.

{history}

Answer the question only based on the context provide below:
{context}

Here is a question:
{question}"""
```

and I have this chain

```
chain = (
    RunnableParallel({"context": retriever, "question": RunnablePassthrough(), "history": history })
    | RunnableLambda(prompt_router)
    | model
    | StrOutputParser()
)
```

How do I pass in the `history` to the chain properly?

I'm getting:

`TypeError: Expected a Runnable, callable or dict.Instead got an unsupported type: <class 'langchain.memory.chat_message_histories.in_memory.ChatMessageHistory'>`

I'll like to convert the chathistory into a Runnable

Comment: [RunnableWithMessageHistory][1] might be what you are looking for


  [1]: https://python.langchain.com/docs/expression_language/how_to/message_history

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following -

```
class InMemoryHistory(BaseChatMessageHistory, BaseModel):
    """In memory implementation of chat message history."""

    messages: List[BaseMessage] = Field(default_factory=list)

    def add_message(self, message: BaseMessage) -> None:
        """Add a self-created message to the store"""
        self.messages.append(message)

    def clear(self) -> None:
        self.messages = []


def get_session_history(user_id: str, conversation_id: str) -> BaseChatMessageHistory:
    if (user_id, conversation_id) not in store:
        store[(user_id, conversation_id)] = InMemoryHistory()
    return store[(user_id, conversation_id)]



 prompt = ChatPromptTemplate.from_messages(
    [
        (
            "system",
            """Use the following pieces of context to answer the question at the end.
            If you don't know the answer, just say that you don't know, don't try to make up an answer.
            Always return a response formatted in MARKDOWN language.
            Always say "thanks for asking!" at the end of the answer.
                
            {context}""",
        ),
        MessagesPlaceholder(variable_name="history"),
        ("human", "{question}"),
    ]
)

context = itemgetter("question") | base_retriever | format_docs
first_step = RunnablePassthrough.assign(context=context)
chain = first_step | prompt | llm

with_message_history = RunnableWithMessageHistory(
    chain,
    get_session_history=get_session_history,
    input_messages_key="question",
    history_messages_key="history",
    history_factory_config=[
        ConfigurableFieldSpec(
            id="user_id",
            annotation=str,
            name="User ID",
            description="Unique identifier for the user.",
            default="",
            is_shared=True,
        ),
        ConfigurableFieldSpec(
            id="conversation_id",
            annotation=str,
            name="Conversation ID",
            description="Unique identifier for the conversation.",
            default="",
            is_shared=True,
        ),
    ],
)

response =  with_message_history.invoke(
        {"question": question},
        config={
            "configurable": {"user_id": "user_id", "conversation_id": "conversation_id"}
        },
    )

answer = response.content

history.add_message(HumanMessage(content=question))
history.add_message(AIMessage(content=answer))

print(response)
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the API > https://api.python.langchain.com/en/latest/runnables/langchain_core.runnables.history.RunnableWithMessageHistory.html

which describes how `RunnableWithMessageHistory` can be defined.

From your code, the error message (which is reproduce-able) comes from

```py
    RunnableParallel({"context": retriever, "question": RunnablePassthrough(),
                      "history": history})
```

Indicating that the format of data fed to `RunnableParallel` isn't expected.

Another reference that you *may* take >
https://python.langchain.com/docs/expression_language/how_to/map